# Python: how to iterate thru a folder to find all "docx"

Tags: python, text, global

I need help writing a for loop to find all ".docx" files then edit them and save them under a new name.

1. I have some code that works for a single file
2. I need code that iterates thru a folder and picks up only the "docx."
3. After editing, save them into another folder.
   a) Retain the *current file name and put it in another folder

Code below:

```
import docx
import os

directory = '.'   #set dir of all *docx files"
extension = '.docx' # editable files must be "docx"
text = ''  #not sure what this is doing here. 

#The for loop to check that all the .docx are found in folder. Edit them regx. BUT I do not know the proper syntax for "file" ending in "docx"

for "file" in os.listdir(directory) #
  if "file".endswith(extension)

def replacer(p, replace_dict):
    inline = p.runs  # Specify the list being used
    for j in range(0, len(inline)):

        # Iterate over the dictionary
        for k, v in replace_dict.items():
            if k in inline[j].text:
                inline[j].text = inline[j].text.replace(k, v)
    return p


# Replace Paragraphs
doc = docx.Document("5538AP_7975_D1.docx")  # Get a file BUT I need all files with different part names.
dict = {'Don Steel': 'TAN', '5538AP':'5499AP', 'Special Mask Build Notes': 'Special Mask Build Notes: Special New receipts for TAN 4X to 5X'}  # Build the dict
for p in doc.paragraphs:  # If needed, iter over paragraphs
    p = replacer(p, dict)  # Call the new replacer function
doc.save("/newOrder/SUBSTITUTE_5538AP1.docx") # need to save all files with their original name in a new folder "newOrder".
```

Comment: That looks not like vbscript. I guess it's Python.

Comment: Your title says VB script, but the provided code in your question is Python.

Comment: I mistakingly labeled my question as a VB script instead of the correct label of Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple answer but effective, you could use the `glob` module as this has direct pattern searching builtin. See the following example

```py
import glob
for i in glob.glob('E:\drivers\\**\\*.pdf', recursive=True):
    print(i)
```

This would look at all the files in `E:\Drivers\` then look through every sub directory and look for pdf files. You can see more at the documentation page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

Comment: I could not edit all the docx files from a single directory or save the newly edited docx file into another directory. I am not getting far with it.

Comment: Hey! That seems a little off-topic with this question you asked here, if you are looking for a new answer then you can create a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

If my answer helped it would be helpful to mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    # NEW FUNCTION:
    import docx
    import glob
    for i in glob.glob(r'C:\Users\LOCAL\Documents\TOPPAN_MOR_BASE_PART\*.docx', recursive=True):

        def replacer(p, replace_dict):
            inline = p.runs  # Specify the list being used
            for j in range(0, len(inline)):

            # Iterate over the dictionary
                for k, v in replace_dict.items():
                    if k in inline[j].text:
                        inline[j].text = inline[j].text.replace(k, v)
            return p


    # Replace Paragraphs
    file_suffix = raw_input(i)
    doc = docx.Document(".docx")  # Get the file
    dict = {'Don Coffman': 'TOPPAN', 'MG5459APSIM':'MG5499AP', 'Special Mask Build Notes': 'Special Mask Build Notes: Special Mask Build Notes: TOPPAN 4X to 5X'}  # Build the dict
    for p in doc.paragraphs:  # If needed, iter over paragraphs
        p = replacer(p, dict)  # Call the new replacer function
```

doc.save(r'C:\Users\LOCAL\Documents\TOPPAN_MOR_BASE_PART\NewOrder\SUBSTITUTE'+file_suffix+'docx')